# How to Backup running EC2 instances with EBS root volumes?

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I am new to AWS and had to take over an existing VPC with multiple EC2 instances.

I am looking for a way to backup the instances (whole disks).

I read about EBS snapshots on forums and this seems a good solution.

The instances' root disks are all EBS volumes.

I read the [AWS documentation on EBS snapshot](http://%22http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html%22) which states as shown below:

> To create a snapshot for Amazon EBS volumes that serve as root devices, you should stop the instance before taking the snapshot.

I cannot shutdown the EC2 instances just for a backup.

How do senior AWS sysadmins back up their instances with EBS root volumes ?

With KVM it is possible to pause a host. Is there a similar functionality available in AWS?

Comment: The link you have provided for amazon resource is not working

Comment: There's a typo in the link, it should be this. But also, I really want to know the answer to this too -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html